# EF4 error:The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

hi I have a question I'am using for my web site wscf in vs2010 that use de model MVP(model,view,presenter) and for my model layer (data acces layer) iam using EF

that seguimiento's tables is an intermediate table between be cliente and gventa tables
so I have my Insert in seguimiento's table with L2E in my (DAL LAYER)like this

```
public void InsertarSeguimiento(Seguimiento Seg)
    {
        using (var cont = new CelumarketingEntities())
        {
            cont.AddToSeguimiento(Seg);
            cont.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

and in my presentation'S layer, I capture for my web form, from textbox the field for seguimiento And I get these error when I try to put the object cliente to  (seguimiento) objProxy.ClienteReference.Value
**The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.**
and I don't understand why since gventa object have no that error

```
 protected void BtnInsertar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nombreGVentas = TbxVendedor.Text;
            char[] delimit = new char[] { ' ' };
            string[] arreglo = nombreGVentas.Split(delimit);
            GVenta IdGVentas = _presenter.getventas(arreglo[0], arreglo[1]);

            string nombrecliente = TbxCliente.Text;
            Project.CAD.Cliente  idCliente = _presenter.getCliente(nombrecliente);

            string hora = DdlHora.SelectedValue;
            string minutos = DdlMinutos.SelectedValue;

            string HorMin = hora + ":" + minutos;
            Project.CAD.Seguimiento objProxy = new Project.CAD.Seguimiento();

            objProxy.GVentaReference.Value = IdGVentas;
            objProxy.ClienteReference.Value = idCliente;   *// here i get the errors*
            objProxy.Descripccion = TbxDescripccion.Text;
            objProxy.Fecha = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
            objProxy.Hora = HorMin;

             _presenter.insertarseg(objProxy);   
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is that your idCliente is already attached to the context here:

```
Project.CAD.Cliente  idCliente = _presenter.getCliente(nombrecliente);
```

So, when you try to assign it to the other object that's also in some other context (the line where you get the error), the EF throws error since it don't know what object to put in what context (it can belong to only one context).

What you need to do is to detach idCliente from it's context before returning in `_presenter.getCliente()` method.

Comment: I dont understand why is that? if my tree object or tables are from the same context? sorry but Iam new on this, it is posible because Iam in a n-layer aplication and I have to use Self Tracking Entities?

Comment: Every time you instantiate context it's a new context, completely separate from all other contexts. When you use some context to fetch entities, all of those entities are attached to that context. In order to work with the same context, you should pass around the context instance as an argument of your functions. BUT, the context isn't serializable - if you're working with n-tier application where context has to pass through multiple services, you should use Self tracking entities. If it's just n-layered (multiple projects in one solution), then it depends on your design.