# The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I want add and edit items in Users. I use this code:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
private void Save()
{
    User user = (SelectedUser == null) ? new User() : db.User.Find(SelectedUser.UserName);
    user.FirstName = FirstName;
    user.CcRowIndex = CcRowIndex;
    user.Image = Image;
    user.LastName = LastName;
    user.OrganizationalPostId = OrganizationalPost;
    user.OrganizationalUnitId = OrganizationalUnit;
    user.Password = Password;
    user.Signature = Signature;
    user.SubsetUsers = SubsetUsersList;
    user.UserName = UserName;
    if (SelectedUser == null)
    {
        db.User.Add(user);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I add Items, but when I edit items I get error:

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.+ savechange of datacontext

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF4 error:The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046843/ef4-errorthe-relationship-between-the-two-objects-cannot-be-defined-because-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to see the definition of your `User` class, however, I can take a guess.

Assumption:

- The `SubsetUsersList` property is a collection of other `User` instances

The `SubsetUsersList` is populated from another instance of your `DbContext`. When you attempt to use these entities in the new instance of `DbContext`, EF complains.

```
// SubsetUsersList populated by unknown DbContext instance
user.SubsetUsers = SubsetUsersList;

// db instance throws exception
db.SaveChanges();
```

An alternative is to load these users in the current `db` instance:

```
// Guessing at the definition of your User class
var subsetUserIds = SubsetUsersList.Select(u => u.UserId).ToArray();
user.SubsetUsers = db.User.Where(u => subsetUserIds.Contains(u.UserId).ToList();
```

This is not efficient, but should help you understand the issue here.